# Cannot initialize a moment instance with a unix timestamp generated from moment (Invalid date)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm confused about these two code samples

Assuming we have a Unix timestamp generated from moment

```
moment().format('x');

Result: 1441721685361
```

Code snippet 1

```
moment(1441721685361);

Result: moment object with date Tue Sep 08 2015 15:14:45 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

Code snippet 2

```
moment(moment().format('x'));

Result: Invalid date
```

If moment().format('x') returns an integer why can't I then use it within moment() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moment().format('x')` returns **string**, [but expect **number**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-offset/) in case when you pass timestamp, you can convert string to number (add `+` before or use `Number(string)` ) and pass to moment, like this

```js
console.log(typeof moment().format('x'));
console.log(moment(+moment().format('x')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Facepalm. It's been a long day... Good spot!